# is "great many thanks" a correction expression and if yes, where is it from?

Tags: grammatical-number

I've seen the expression "great many thanks" at the end of many online postings and have always wondered if the expression is grammatically correct. It appears that a similar expression "a great many thanks" also seems quite popular and is a "standard" English expression.

Why is "a" great many thanks standard English and is "great many thanks" itself a good grammar English expression?

Any thought? Thank you.

Comment: I have a feeling that it's just an abbreviated version of, "Great. Many thanks" or "Great, many thanks," both of which would require more typing, when in cyberspace, every character saved is [a character earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71283/why-are-there-maximum-character-limits-in-comments-and-posts).

Comment: @Teacher KSHuang: Sorry, this is incorrect. You will frequently see this phrased as "**a** great many thanks". The indefinite article indicates that it is a single noun phrase. I would interpret it as an ellipsis: "(Please receive / I give you) a great many thanks." I'm adding this as a comment because I can't exactly say whether it's "Standard English" and where it came from, as requested by the OP. But correct English it is. ;)

Comment: ? I see ParaDice's comment, but just a simple search online will show you that all three are possible: "[A great many thanks](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g31352-d1383010-r128135093-Barlow_Jeep_Rentals-Sedona_Arizona.html)," "[Great, many thanks](https://medium.com/@theonlytoby/this-is-great-many-thanks-for-writing-it-3d00fd1f04e4)," and "Great. [Many thanks.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/is-many-thanks-a-proper-usage)" so you will have to decide for yourself which people mean when they just type "great many thanks."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "a great many thanks" is used to sign off a written exchange (letter, email, etc). It is a standard phrase in that context, it is grammatically correct, but would appear old fashioned in spoken English. The phrase "a great many" means a large amount, but again would appear old fashioned.